# How to copy specific sheet name from excel and save it to a new location? Using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am using C# Windows Forms.

**Goal:**

If I have multiple excel sheets.

For example, `"Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, TestSheet1, TestSheet2"`

How can I grab specific sheet name e.g. `["Sheet2"]` and save it as a new excel workbook?

This is what I have so far:

**Button Click:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\LV98\Desktop\Test C#\excel_file.xlsx");

    excelBook.Worksheets.Copy("Sheet2");
}
```

**Update:**

Here is where I got to.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Application excelApp;

    string fileTarget = "C:\\Users\\LV98\\Desktop\\Test C#\\template.xlsx";
    string fileTemplate = "C:\\Users\\LV98\\Desktop\\Test C#\\excel_file.xlsx";
    excelApp = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook wbTarget;
    Excel.Worksheet sh;

    //Create target workbook
    wbTarget = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileTemplate);

    //Fill target workbook
    //Open the template sheet
    sh = wbTarget.Worksheets["Sheet2"];
    sh.Copy(wbTarget.Worksheets[1]);


    //Save file
    wbTarget.SaveAs(fileTarget);
    wbTarget.Close(true);
    excelApp.Quit();

}
```

When I open the new excel file, it opens "Sheet2", just what I was after! But only problem is, there is other sheets saved too.. I will be looking into renaming the new sheet - and delete the rest.

Comment: do you want to save all worksheet or only particular worksheet?

Comment: @UdhayTitus particular worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this in your code it will be works

```
foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in wbTarget.Worksheets)
            {
                //Save Particular sheet as file
                if (sheet.Name == "Sheet2")
                {
                    var newbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(1);
                    sheet.Copy(newbook.Sheets[1]);

                    newbook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\LV98\Desktop\Test C#\" + sheet.Name);
                    newbook.Close();
                }
            }
```

complete code of your button click event. I tested the below code and it's working fine

```
protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application excelApp;

        string fileTemplate = "C:\\Users\\LV98\\Desktop\\Test C#\\template.xlsx";            
        excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook wbTarget;

        //Create target workbook
        wbTarget = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileTemplate);

        foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in wbTarget.Worksheets)
        {
            //Save Particular sheet as file
            if (sheet.Name == "Sheet2")
            {
                var newbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(1);
                sheet.Copy(newbook.Sheets[1]);

                newbook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\LV98\Desktop\Test C#\" + sheet.Name);
                newbook.Close();
            }
        }
        wbTarget.Close(true);
        excelApp.AskToUpdateLinks = false;
        excelApp.Quit();
        GetExcelProcess(excelApp);
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(int hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);
    Process GetExcelProcess(Excel.Application excelApp)
    {
        int id;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(excelApp.Hwnd, out id);
        return Process.GetProcessById(id);
    }
```

Comment: @LV98 sorry I'm not getting, can you explain me the problem exactly?

Comment: this line of code `string fileTemplate = "C:\\Users\\LV98\\Desktop\\Test C#\\template.xlsx";  ` - is the source file where we are getting the sheet name and save it to a new location `newbook.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\LV98\Desktop\Test C#\" + sheet.Name);`- after the application is closed, the original file `template.xlsx` is locked for editing.

Comment: go to task manager and select Process tab, in process tab check whether any process is running by name of `EXCEL.exe`

Comment: That's what I currently do - but need to prevent that from happening in the code. Will do some research into it

Comment: did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17777840/6108882 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/15556843/6108882

Comment: @LV89 can you check the updated answer, it might be works.

Comment: for `template.xlsx` folder give the permissions. Right click on the folder then click properties, then select Security tab and give edit it and give full control for all users.

Comment: can you try this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b81a3c4e-62db-488b-af06-44421818ef91/excel-2007-automation-on-top-of-a-windows-server-2008-x64 or run your application by Administrator login and use our above button click event.

Comment: Check new question - I have answered it there too.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research I came across some useful links. 
I am pasting below a code snippet which I think will help you out:

```
IWorkbook sourceWorkbook = application.Workbooks.Open("Source.xlsx");
IWorkbook destinationWorkbook = application.Workbooks.Open("Destination.xlsx");

//Copy Excel worksheet from source workbook to the destination workbook
destinationWorkbook.Worksheets.AddCopy(sourceWorkbook.Worksheets[0]);

//Save the file
destinationWorkbook.Save();
```

I have found the above code in the following link: [Copy Excel worksheet to another workbook](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/1935/copy-excel-worksheet-to-another-workbook-in-c-vb-net)

Also it I believe that you will find it helpful to read the following answer: [How to copy a single Excel worksheet from one workbook to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808600/8293694)